# Sublime 3 - How do I view stored variables in Sublime like in Matlab's "Workspace"

Tags: python, variables, spyder, workspace

I'm very new to Python and have loads of experience with Matlab. As the code runs, how can I view what is stored in what variable like in Matlab's workspace and Spyder IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Sublime is a text editor, not an IDE. Sublime does not do any code execution, it quite literally just edits text. Viewing variable values during runtime is one of the many features found in programs like Spyder that make them IDEs, not just text editors.

If you're just using Sublime, you'll need to judiciously use print statements to help you debug.

Also, running Python in interactive mode is very helpful. `python -i my_script.py` will load the Python interpreter after executing your script, allowing you to access variables and interact with your live script.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it does help. I was afraid of that. I was hoping for at least some plugin that would contain a list of variables with their type and their respective values.

Is there a way to run Spyder without Anaconda? Sometimes Anaconda won't even startup. Thats the only thing keeping me from using it. I need a standalone version.

Comment: @KrisHoffman, you can install Spyder with pip too: `pip install -U spyder`. I'd recommend you to use a virtualenv to not break your main Python installation (if you're on Linux or macOS), in case errors occur with that.